# VS 2015 R2 crashes - sometimes after just one line of code

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After installing update 2 VS keeps crashing. It would appear to be one project but I can't be totally sure. Sometimes it will run for a good ten minutes, other times I can't get to the end of one line of code (usually when the intellisense pop-up is open).

The log has the following errors

```
<record>379</record>
<time>2016/04/27 20:40:47.732</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Extension Manager</source>
<description>Error loading extension: This VSIX does not apply to any 
product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX     manifest&apos;s format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. </description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\VSGRAPHICS\</path>

<record>380</record>
<time>2016/04/27 20:40:47.798</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Extension Manager</source>
<description>Error loading extension: This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest&apos;s format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. </description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\VSGRAPHICS\</path>


<record>381</record>
<time>2016/04/27 20:40:47.798</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Extension Manager</source>
<description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Extensions&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\404LS5J3.TPA\...</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TEAMFOUNDATION\TEAM EXPLORER\</path>





<record>409</record>
<time>2016/04/27 20:40:48.090</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Extension Manager</source>
<description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK\...</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\</path>
```

With VSIX I looked at the manifest file Extension.vsixmanifest and it helpfully (not) just contained the line 'The contents of this file have moved.'

I should also add that it running in safe mode doesn't prevent a crash. I was under the impression that extensions are not loaded in safe mode, if so this is going to be interesting.

Somewhere I read that the extension 'Automatic Versions' was causing this behavior after update 2, but checking extension manager that was not listed...

Any pointers would be very much appreciated :-)

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Nope - still driving me totally mental. I have, however, noticed that it only does it with some projects and not others. Still no answer from MS.

Comment: Restarting fixes it for me, but it's always temporary. I've tried everything—even the TotalUninstaller program MS put on GitHub to erase all traces of VS. I'm at a loss.

Comment: I ran fix, re-install - everything I could think of! Usually just typing something simple like String.Replace will cause it to crash - or pausing for a second when Intellisense is open. Got to the stage where I type a lot of code in NotePad and paste into VS.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Python solution in VS2015 Community after installing VS2015 Update 3. It would not load the projects. However I had no problems with the C++ solutions.

I did not have the automatic extension loaded, so I installed it.
Then the Python projects did load. Sometimes they would fail to load again, but I right clicked and reloaded them.